# cake 3:- how to use htaccess RewriteRule in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am working on cake 3.

i have a cake 3 URL:- www.test.com/users/account/john

and want this URL like www.test.com/john

i don't have any idea how to do this,
please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// config/routes.php

Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    //...
    // add at end 
    $routes->connect('/*', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'account']);

}


//

//UsersController.php

public function account($slug = null){
 // your code here
}

// in view
echo $this->Html->link('John',['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'account','john']);
```